# YiiFramwork-Clear current render data and render new data instead of redirect

Tags: php, redirect, yii, render

I would like to ask if there is such a case that I can clear off the current rendered page and then re render with a set of new layout? I know i can achieve this by calling redirect but i would have to create another set of action just to handle 1 layout. Is there a way that I can do it in one action? This is how I do it currently but i cant seem to clear off the previous layout and render another set of new layout...

```
/**
 * Change a user's password
 * @param int $id Owner's id
 *
 */
public function actionChngPassword($id)
{
    $this->pageTitle = 'Change Password';

    $model=Users::model()->findByPk($id);
    $model->scenario = 'chngPwd';
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    $returnUrl = Yii::app()->homeUrl;

    if(isset($_POST['Users'])){
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Users'];
        if($model->validate()){
            $model->scenario = "";
            $ip = Users::getRealIp();
            $time = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
            $name = $model->usrname;

            $model->old_pwd = $model->pwd;
            $model->pwd = CPasswordHelper::hashPassword($model->newpwd);
            $model->pw_change_on = $time = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
            $model->save();

            // Send email noti to user
            $revert_link= $this->createAbsoluteUrl('users/revertPassword', array('id' => $model->user_id, 'pwhash' => urlencode($model->pwd)));

            ob_start();
            $INC_DIR = UrlMgmt::getBaseAbsoluteUrl() . "/protected/views/users/mailtemplate/";
            include($INC_DIR . "pwChange_email.php");
            $view = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();

            Mailer::sendMail('Viralenz Member Accounts Management', $model->email_addr, 'Viralenz Password Changed!', $view);

            Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag("3;url={$returnUrl}", null, 'refresh');
            $this->render('msg_pwchange',array('c'=>"change"));
        }

    }

    $this->render('chngPassword', array('model' => $model));

}
```

Noticed that the second render part appended on top... I want it to clear all and re render a set of new layout...

[image: Re Render]

Is there any other approach that I can use instead of redirecting to another action?

Comment: May be you can try ajax to render the new page!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using ajax to render, you can replace the view "chngPassword" with "msg_pwchange" without redirecting to other action.
Provide an id(eg: response_id) to the outer element of "chngPassword" and make an ajax call while clicking the "Change" button as below:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {...provide here...},
            url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->getbaseurl(TRUE). '/controller_id/ChngPassword' ?>',
            success: function(str) {
                $('#response_id').html(str);
            }
        });
```

Modification to Controller Action:

```
public function actionChngPassword($id){
```

-----custom codes-----------

```
if(isset($_POST['Users'])){
```

-----custom codes------

```
        $this->renderPartial('msg_pwchange',array('c'=>"change"));
    }

}

$this->render('chngPassword', array('model' => $model));
```

}

Function renderPartial() only returns view of particular file without layout. Now we can replace previous view with new view(ajax response).